# How to create a durable consumer (subscriber) in Masstransit using ActiveMQ as transport?

Tags: masstransit, activemq-artemis

I'm setting up the foundation for a larger application and want to make the setup correct. I am used to Azure Service Bus and some RabbitMQ but not ActiveMQ and Masstransit. Seems like a good combo though, BUT not that much documentation or example projects out there.

Do you have a hint/ tips on how to make receiving endpoints durable so that message are stored on disc when published from Topic.

I have somehow figured out that it should be configured on receiving end and close to Transport configuration (ActiveMQ Artemis):

```
services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
{
    //var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    //busConfigurator.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);

    busConfigurator.AddConsumer<JournalHasBeenViewedMessageConsumer>(typeof(JournalHasBeenViewedMessageConsumer), (consumeConfig) =>
    {
    });

    busConfigurator.UsingActiveMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("localhost", 61616, h =>
        {
            h.Username("admin");
            h.Password("admin");
        });

        cfg.EnableArtemisCompatibility();

        // Here right?

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
});
```

Above code that I register one of the consumers. How do I make this durable? According to [MassTransit docs](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/transports/activemq) it should be somewhere:

> MassTransit includes several receive endpoint level configuration options that control receive endpoint behavior...
>
> | Property | Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Durable | bool | If true, messages are persisted to disk before being acknowledged (default: true) |

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: Locally using a docker image from Masstransit team that seems to hold version Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.12 (hmm not artemis - But I know we have Artemis on production)

Comment: docker image is masstransit/activemq:latest

Comment: So...are you asking about ActiveMQ "Classic" or Artemis?

Comment: Is there u huge difference? Im asking about Artemis, since that is setup in our production.

Comment: I don't know if there's a huge difference at this point. I'm just trying to understand the question.

Comment: Question is - How to I configure Receiver/Consumer to be Durable through Masstransit Configuration? The documentation is not that good

Comment: I don't know. I work on ActiveMQ not MassTransit.

Comment: Do you have good documentation of how to implement Publish/subscribe with pure .net client?

Comment: Client documentation is typically provided by the actual client library. The broker does ship a Java client along with JMS facade for that client, but the broker mainly just supports _protocols_. There are lots of clients on lots of platforms implemented via lots of different languages that can interact with the broker via the various protocols it supports. So from a broker perspective it's not really about the language or the platform but rather what protocol the client speaks. Asking about a "pure .net client" doesn't mean much without know what protocol it's using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MassTransit receive endpoints on ActiveMQ are durable by default, nothing special needs to be done.

Comment: I didn't know that. Why I wrote this question is due to Apache ActiveMQ Console and I couldnt find the durable consumer. But your answer made me look closer. I can know see that when I start my Consumer it also creates a Queue and in console I can also see my Consumer (Subscriber) is active. However, I tested though to publish my message from my Topic when Consumer is offline and it doesnt copy message to Consumer queue (so that Consumer can consume it when it goes online). BUT it works when both Topic and Consumer is online, then Publish message trigger consumer. Why not queued when offline?

Comment: Hmm After futher testing I know see that when I remove cfg.EnableArtemisCompatibility() both from configuring Topic and Consumer It actually works.

Comment: Artemis works differently, you should only use that setting when you're on an Artemis broker.